# In ElasticSearch, is there a way to get the number of terms matched for each match returned by ES for a term query request?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, term-query

For a given term query search request, will i be able to find the number terms matched for each of the value returned by ElasticSearch?

**If suppose i have a input as -**

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "message" : "this is a test"
        }
    }
}
```

and for this **if suppose i get matched values as - 'this man' and 'this man test'.**

here the number of terms matched wrt the request for **'this man' is 1** and for **'this man test' is 2.**

Is there a way to directly get this number in the response?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) to count exact sentences :

```
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": "this is a test"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "genres": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "message.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
```

Note that will need a mapping with a text (for the match query) and a keyword (for the agg). This is the default mapping in ElasticSearch.

Depends of your need [Significant text aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-bucket-significanttext-aggregation.html) may also interest you